# Split vertex(s) in two, creating new faces

Tags: vertices

I would like to be able to select vertices or edges and duplicate them, but also keep the faces filled.

My example:
[image]
[image]

So something like a Rip and fill function, but also creates the faces on both edges?

Comment: Use the bevel edge function.

Comment: Bevel would require quite a bit of clean-up after using, probably even more if just ripping and filling in manually. There is Rip Fill tool.

Answer (score 0):

Bevel the edge and fill the faces manually, there is no such thing as a split and fill in Blender.

Comment: Would that be a technically difficult function to create? Must be if it doesnt exist..

Comment: There is.. Alt+V before 2.8 shortcuts or Rip Fill https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/vertices.html#rip-vertices-and-fill